# Read all contacts' phone numbers in android

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts, phone-number

I'm using this code to retrieve all contact names and phone numbers:

```
String[] projection = new String[]
{
    People.NAME,
    People.NUMBER
};

Cursor c = ctx.getContentResolver().query(People.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, People.NAME + " ASC");
c.moveToFirst();

int nameCol = c.getColumnIndex(People.NAME);
int numCol = c.getColumnIndex(People.NUMBER);

int nContacts = c.getCount();

do
{
  // Do something
} while(c.moveToNext());
```

However, this will only return the primary number for each contact, but I want to get the secondary numbers as well. How can i do this?

Comment: try [android contact extractor](https://github.com/nitiwari-dev/android-contact-extractor). A small simple easy to use library

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can read all of the telephone numbers associated with a contact in the following manner:

```
Uri personUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(People.CONTENT_URI, personId);
Uri phonesUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(personUri, People.Phones.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
String[] proj = new String[] {Phones._ID, Phones.TYPE, Phones.NUMBER, Phones.LABEL}
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(phonesUri, proj, null, null, null);
```

Please note that this example (like yours) uses the deprecated contacts API. From eclair onwards this has been replaced with the [ContactsContract](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html) API.

Answer (score 154):

Following code shows an easy way to read all phone numbers and names:

```
Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
while (phones.moveToNext())
{
  String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
  String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

}
phones.close();
```

> **NOTE:** `getContentResolver` is a method from the `Activity` context.

Comment: Thank you, this single query method is 100 times faster!

Comment: Significant faster but contact name may be duplicated if that contact has more than 1 number.

Comment: @Dinesh Kumar Which is retrieve all the contacts but i need user selected single contacts

Comment: how to avoid duplicate here?

Comment: It only get some little contacts! In my case, `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI` gets me 361 contact but `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI` gets me 5115 contact! What is difference?!

Comment: it craete duplicate contacts.
so @AsifSb use below cursor
`cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);`

Answer (score 26):

This code shows how to get **all** phone numbers for each contact.

```
ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(
                  ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(
                  ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(
                   ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
             Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                      ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                      null, 
                      ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", 
                      new String[]{id}, null);
             while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                  int phoneType = pCur.getInt(pCur.getColumnIndex(
                      ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
                  String phoneNumber = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(
                      ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                  switch (phoneType) {
                        case Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                            Log.e(name + "(mobile number)", phoneNumber);
                            break;
                        case Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                            Log.e(name + "(home number)", phoneNumber);
                            break;
                        case Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                            Log.e(name + "(work number)", phoneNumber);
                            break;
                        case Phone.TYPE_OTHER:
                            Log.e(name + "(other number)", phoneNumber);
                            break;                                  
                        default:
                            break;
                  }
              } 
              pCur.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @anivaler. I've tried to implement your solution in my code but it doesn't work well. Show the correct number but when I do scroll change the numbers. Can you take a look at my question, please. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38978923/recyclerview-change-the-value-of-my-phonenumber-in-contactscontract-when-scroll/38979586?noredirect=1#comment65314036_38979586

Comment: hi i have implement it work fine but i didn't get what is wrong with it , it shows phone number with name more than 2 times but when i checked it in phone the same number and name is comes only one time

Answer (score 14):

In case it helps, I've got an example that uses the ContactsContract API to first find a contact by name, then it iterates through the details looking for specific number types:

[How to use ContactsContract to retrieve phone numbers and email addresses](http://www.androidref.com/#ContactsContract)

Answer (score 11):

You can get all phone contacts using this:

```
    Cursor c = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                    ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE },
            ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " <> 'google' ",
            null, null);
```

check complete example [HERE](https://gagandroid.blogspot.in/2015/03/get-all-phone-contacts-in-android.html)...........

Comment: For my ~ 800 contacts, the codes in this answer run for 89 ms, but the other way (query for contact id then phone numbers for each id) used 23 000 ms !

Comment: Super fast! best answer

Answer (score 10):

```
String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) 
{
    System.out.println("name : " + name + ", ID : " + id);

    // get the <span id="IL_AD4" class="IL_AD">phone
    // number</span>
    Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                           null, 
                           ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);

    while (pCur.moveToNext())
    {
        String phone = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        System.out.println("phone" + phone);
    }

pCur.close();
```

Answer (score 3):

Accepted answer working but not given unique numbers.

See this code, it return unique numbers.

```
public static void readContacts(Context context) {
        if (context == null)
            return;
        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

        if (contentResolver == null)
            return;

        String[] fieldListProjection = {
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER
        };

        Cursor phones = contentResolver
                .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI
                        , fieldListProjection, null, null, null);
        HashSet<String> normalizedNumbersAlreadyFound = new HashSet<>();

        if (phones != null && phones.getCount() > 0) {
            while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                String normalizedNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER));
                if (Integer.parseInt(phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                    if (normalizedNumbersAlreadyFound.add(normalizedNumber)) {
                        String id = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
                        String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        Log.d("test", " Print all values");
                    }
                }
            }
            phones.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In the same way just get their other numbers using the other "People" references

```
People.TYPE_HOME
People.TYPE_MOBILE
People.TYPE_OTHER
People.TYPE_WORK
```

Answer (score 1):

This [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989575/retrieving-phone-contacts-on-android-3-0) finally gave me the answer I was looking for. It lets you retrieve all the names and phone numbers of the contacts on the phone.

```
package com.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;

public class TestContacts extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                              null, null, null, null);
        if (cur != null && cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {

                if (Integer.parseInt.equals(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)))) {
                    String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(
                                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(
                                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                                           ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                    + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
                    int i = 0;
                    int pCount = pCur.getCount();
                    String[] phoneNum = new String[pCount];
                    String[] phoneType = new String[pCount];
                    while (pCur != null && pCur.moveToNext()) {
                        phoneNum[i] = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        phoneType[i] = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
                        i++;
                    }
                }

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Downvotes without an explanation really shouldn't be allowed, but I've updated my code to what it is now. I use this code currently. If there's a typo or something that's keeping it from working properly, let me know, and I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my need belove

manifest permissions

```
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
        <!-- Read Contacts from phone -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.read_contacts" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.read_phone_state" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
```

**Note: After giving permissions at manifest some mobile phones can deny if so you need to go Settings--> Applications--> find your application click on it and
turn On the permissions needed**

[image]

```
 btn_readallcontacks.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
            List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
            while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                User user = new User();
                user.setNamee(phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)));
                user.setPhone(phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
                userList.add(user);
                Log.d(TAG, "Name : " + user.getNamee().toString());
                Log.d(TAG, "Phone : " + user.getPhone().toString());
            }
            phones.close();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the contact all those which have no number and all those which have no name from this piece of code

```
public void readContacts() {
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, ContactsContract.RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " ASC");
    ContactCount = cur.getCount();

    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phone = null;
            if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                System.out.println("name : " + name + ", ID : " + id);

                // get the phone number
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[]{id}, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    phone = pCur.getString(
                            pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    System.out.println("phone" + phone);
                }
                pCur.close();
            }
            if (phone == "" || name == "" || name.equals(phone)) {
                if (phone.equals(""))
                    getAllContact.add(new MissingPhoneModelClass("No Number", name, id));
                if (name.equals("") || name.equals(phone))
                    getAllContact.add(new MissingPhoneModelClass(phone, "No Name", id));

            } else {
                if(TextUtils.equals(phone,null)){
                    getAllContact.add(new MissingPhoneModelClass("No Number", name, id));
                }
                else {
                    getAllContact.add(new MissingPhoneModelClass(phone, name, id));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One thing can be done you have to give the permission in the manifest for contact READ and WRITE
After that you can create the model class for the list which can be use to add all the contact here is the model class

```
public class PhoneModelClass {
private String number;
private String name;
private String id;
private String rawId;

public PhoneModelClass(String number, String name, String id, String rawId) {
    this.number = number;
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.rawId = rawId;
}

public PhoneModelClass(String number, String name, String id) {
    this.number = number;
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
}

public String getRawId() {
    return rawId;
}

public void setRawId(String rawId) {
    this.rawId = rawId;
}

public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(String number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: NOTE: this code is slow because it creates a new query for each contact

Comment: it is used for more than one phone number in a single contact that's why it checks if the contact has more then one number use it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Load contacts in background using CursorLoader:

```
  CursorLoader cursor = new CursorLoader(this, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
            Cursor managedCursor = cursor.loadInBackground();

            int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.DATA1);
            int name = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
            int index = 0;
            while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
                String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
                String phName = managedCursor.getString(name);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to use `ContentsContract` API to fetch your contacts in your Phone Book.
You'll need to add these permissions in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Then, you can run this method to loop through all your contacts.

Here's an example to query fields like Name and Phone Number, you can configure yourself to use CommonDataKinds, it query other fields in your Contact.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds

```kotlin
private fun readContactsOnDevice() {
    val context = requireContext()
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            context, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS
        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        requestPermissions(
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS), 1
        )
        return
    }

    val contentResolver = context.contentResolver
    val contacts = contentResolver.query(
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
        null, null, null, null
    )

    while (contacts?.moveToNext() == true) {
        val name = contacts.getString(
            contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)
        )
        val phoneNumber = contacts.getString(
            contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)
        )
        Timber.i("Name: $name, Phone Number: $phoneNumber")
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
     package com.example.readcontacts;

        import java.util.ArrayList;

        import android.app.Activity; import android.app.ProgressDialog;
        import android.content.ContentResolver; import
        android.database.Cursor; import android.net.Uri; import
        android.os.Bundle; import android.os.Handler; import
        android.provider.ContactsContract; import android.view.View; import
        android.widget.AdapterView; import
        android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener; import
        android.widget.ArrayAdapter; import android.widget.ListView; import
        android.widget.Toast;

        public class MainActivity extends Activity {    private ListView
        mListView;  private ProgressDialog pDialog;     private Handler
        updateBarHandler;

            ArrayList<String> contactList;  Cursor cursor;  int counter;    
            @Override   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);         pDialog.setMessage("Reading
        contacts...");      pDialog.setCancelable(false);       pDialog.show();

                mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);         updateBarHandler
        =new Handler();
                        // Since reading contacts takes more time, let's run it on a separate thread.       new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override           public void run() {
                        getContacts();          }       }).start();

                // Set onclicklistener to the list item.
                mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View
        view,
                            int position, long id) {
                        //TODO Do whatever you want with the list data
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "item clicked : \n"+contactList.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          }
                });     }

            public void getContacts() {


                contactList = new ArrayList<String>();

                String phoneNumber = null;      String email = null;

                Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;        String
        _ID = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;        String DISPLAY_NAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;       String HAS_PHONE_NUMBER =
        ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;

                Uri PhoneCONTENT_URI =
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;         String
        Phone_CONTACT_ID =
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;      String NUMBER =
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;

                Uri EmailCONTENT_URI = 
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI;         String
        EmailCONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID;
                String DATA = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA;

                StringBuffer output;

                ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

                cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null,null, null,
        null);  

                // Iterate every contact in the phone       if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
        {

                    counter = 0;            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        output = new StringBuffer();

                        // Update the progress message
                        updateBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                pDialog.setMessage("Reading contacts : "+ counter++ +"/"+cursor.getCount());
                            }
                        });

                        String contact_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( _ID ));
                        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( DISPLAY_NAME ));

                        int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
        HAS_PHONE_NUMBER )));

                        if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {

                            output.append("\n First Name:" + name);

                            //This is to read multiple phone numbers associated with the same contact
                            Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(PhoneCONTENT_URI, null, Phone_CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { contact_id }, null);

                            while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                                phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(NUMBER));
                                output.append("\n Phone number:" + phoneNumber);

                            }

                            phoneCursor.close();

                            // Read every email id associated with the contact
                            Cursor emailCursor = contentResolver.query(EmailCONTENT_URI,    null, EmailCONTACT_ID+ " =
        ?", new String[] { contact_id }, null);

                            while (emailCursor.moveToNext()) {

                                email = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(DATA));

                                output.append("\n Email:" + email);

                            }

                            emailCursor.close();
                        }

                        // Add the contact to the ArrayList
                        contactList.add(output.toString());             }

                    // ListView has to be updated using a ui thread
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item,
        R.id.text1, contactList);
                            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);          
                        }           });

                    // Dismiss the progressbar after 500 millisecondds
                    updateBarHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            pDialog.cancel();               
                        }           }, 500);        }

            }

        }

List item
```

Answer (score -1):

Code to get contact name (Ascending order) and number

***For more reference: [show contact in listview](http://demonuts.com/2017/05/12/get-contact-list-in-android-studio-listview/)***

```
Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME+" ASC");
        while (phones.moveToNext())
        {
            String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));


        }
        phones.close();
```