# How to get a contact's number from contact name in android

Tags: android

I am having a contacts name with me and want his number .How to get contact number of corresponding name in Android ?

Comment: These are some helpfull links for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356084/read-all-contacts-phone-numbers-in-android     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866769/how-to-call-android-contacts-list

Answer (score 19):

A **shorter** version;
you still need that permission (android.permission.READ_CONTACTS)

```
public String getPhoneNumber(String name, Context context) {
String ret = null;
String selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME+" like'%" + name +"%'";
String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
        projection, selection, null, null);
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    ret = c.getString(0);
}
c.close();
if(ret==null)
    ret = "Unsaved";
return ret;
}
```

Comment: How do I call this from my `main` activity?

Comment: String number=getPhoneNumber(contactName,MainActivity.this);

Answer (score 3):

The following code will log out to logcat all the mobile numbers for a contact with a display name of contactName:

```
Cursor cursor = null;
try {
    cursor = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI,
            new String [] { Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID },
            StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME + "=? AND "
                + Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'",
            new String[] { contactName},  null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String rawContactId = cursor.getString(0);
            Cursor phoneCursor = null;
            try {
                phoneCursor = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI,
                        new String[] {Data._ID, Phone.NUMBER},
                        Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND "
                                + Phone.TYPE + "=" + Phone.TYPE_MOBILE + " AND "
                                + Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'",
                                new String[] {rawContactId}, null);

                if (phoneCursor != null && phoneCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    String number = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
                    Log.d(TAG, "Mobile Number: " + number);
                }
            } finally {
                if (phoneCursor != null) {
                    phoneCursor.close();
                }
            }
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());  
    }
} finally {
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I tried something similar, but it didn't work. Here is my question, I would really appreciate your help! :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097844/get-contact-name/35098111#35098111

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
        people = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, "person_name"+"='"+name+"'", null, null);
        people.moveToFirst();  
         {

            {  

                try{
                    String contactId = people.getString(people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String hasPhone = people.getString(people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
                    if ( hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
                        hasPhone = "true";
                    else
                        hasPhone = "false" ;
                    if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) 
                    {
                        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId,null, null);
                        while (phones.moveToNext()) 
                        {
                            String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                            mConno.add(position,phoneNumber);

                        }
                        phones.close(); 
                    }   
                    if(hasPhone=="false")
                    {   mConname.remove(position);
                    }   
                    else
                        position++;
                }       
                catch(Exception e)
                { 

                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: P.S. You also have to have permission to query Contacts.

Comment: yes u need <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

Comment: Hello, I tried something similar, but it didn't work. Here is my question, I would really appreciate your help! :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097844/get-contact-name/35098111#35098111