# speech recognition and performing actions

Tags: android

i need your help
im developing a speech recognition app, which performs actions such as making a call, sending a message and the familiar stuff..
i managed to program the voice recognition in my app and it works great, but i cant seem to understand how to perform these actions, for example if i tell the app "call michael" , how is it done in coding? how to write calling action\sms action in code?
i would really appreciate any help!

here is a code that describes how i get the word action from speech recognition:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        //check speech recognition result 
        if (requestCode == VOICE_REC_CODE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
        {
            //store the returned word list as an ArrayList
            ArrayList<String> suggestedWords= data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            startExecutingActions(suggestedWords);
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

the question is, how do i execute these actions\commands like; call, send sms, search the web, navigate and more, and use them in startExecutingActions(suggestedWords) function?

Comment: You should fire an intent with the right action: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the given example of calling someone you will need to start a new intent with a phone action.
Here is a list of [common intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html).

Let's say you recognized that the user want's to call a specific number (by looking up the name in your phonebook). Then you can call your "dialNumber" method with the phone number.

```
public void dialNumber(String pNumber){

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PHONE);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + pNumber));
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    };
}
```

You will need to make sure that your app has all the required permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: thanks for the answer, 
do i have to find the number every time the user asks for a new contact, or is there a way that the code would find the contact from the contacts list and then call or sms the contact?

Answer (score 1):

Add this code:

```
if (!suggestedWords.isEmpty()) {
   if (suggestedWords.get(0).contains("call michael")) {
      //Get michael contact phone number
      //Call michael
   }
}
```

---

If you want to get contact phone number, use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12388353/3226984)

---

If you want to call, use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18973484/3226984)

Comment: sorry maybe i wasnt clear, i know how to take the word out, what i dont know is how to tell the application make the call.

Comment: @Lena look at my Edit