# cant read phone contacts

Tags: android, contacts

I am  reading contacts stored in phone and showing them in list view.
My code is as follows:

```
String col[]={ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};

    Cursor  cursorNames = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, col, null, null, null);
    intentContactsToreturn=new Intent();

    ArrayList<String> contactNames=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> contactNumbers=new ArrayList<String>(); 

    try 
    {
        if(cursorNames.getCount() > 0)
        {
            while(cursorNames.moveToNext())
            {           
            String id = cursorNames.getString(cursorNames.getColumnIndex(Contacts._ID));
            contactNames.add(cursorNames.getString(cursorNames.getColumnIndex(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));

            Cursor cursorNumbers =getContentResolver().query(CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
            cursorNumbers.moveToFirst();
            contactNumbers.add(cursorNumbers.getString(cursorNumbers.getColumnIndex(CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));        
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
      cursorNames.close();
    }

   ContactListArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ContactListArrayAdapter(this,contactNames,contactNumbers);
   // lv.addFooterView(b);
   listViewContacts.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```

Now the problem it is reading the SIM contacts (and not phone contacts) also it is not reading all the contacts in SIM.

It is reading  some of the contacts in SIM and exact number is  15 (while in SiM there are  100+ contacts) and also it repeats the contacts in list view.

like this

15 contacts
then again the same 15 contacts are reapeating in list view.

again and again total 4 times 15 contacts are repeated.

Comment: Try to call cursor.moveToFirst before you're starting to iterate over the cursor, maybe this will resolve the issue.

Comment: hope you added Permission of READ_CONTACTS.

Comment: [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356084/read-all-contacts-phone-numbers-in-android