# Retrieve contacts by user selection with intent

Tags: android, android-intent, contacts

So i'm trying to create a button in android studio that will open a contacts selection box that looks like the contacts selection when sending S.M.S (allow to choose more than one contact, letting you choose groups of contacts).

1. i have tried this code, but it only letting you choose one contact:

   ```
   private static final int CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT = 1001;

   public void doLaunchContactPicker(View view) {
   Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
   startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);
   }
   ```
2. after the user will select the contacts, how will i get the info?

## update:

as @Allu i didn't find a way that i wont have to design this all by myself.
eventually i wrote this code to get the groups and used ListView to display them to the users:

```
public class myGroup {
private String _ID;
private String _TITLE;
private ArrayList<String> _PHONE_NUMBERS;

     public  myGroup(String id, String title){
        _ID = id;
        _TITLE = title;
        //get the contacts phone numbers
        //_PHONE_NUMBERS.add();
     }
}

private ArrayList<myGroup> getGroups(){
    ArrayList<myGroup> myGroups = new ArrayList<myGroup>();
    Cursor cursor =getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI,new String[]{ContactsContract.Groups._ID, ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE}, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int len = cursor.getCount();
    String[] a = cursor.getColumnNames();
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Groups.DELETED) == 1){
            continue;
        }
        myGroups.add(new myGroup(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Groups._ID)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE))));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    return myGroups;
}
```

Comment: please check this links it may helpful  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449416/android-multiple-contacts-chooser-with-option-of-choosing-which-phone-number     ,,,,                                        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620805/how-to-select-multiple-contacts-from-the-phone-using-checkboxes

Comment: @Allu and what with the groups view?

Comment: i didn't get you, means you want to send  sms for one group which is added with some contacts

Comment: @Allu can i show the user the lists of the groups?, then he will choose what groups he wants to send SMS to?

Comment: i don't know much about just see this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334649/accessing-android-contact-group-names     otherwise    programmatically you can create group with some contacts and show that groups when he clicks on select groups              search in net you can find good  solutions.