# Get all phone numbers from contacts

Tags: android, phone-number

I use the following code to retrieve all phone number from contacts.

```
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(
                        Data.CONTENT_URI,
                        new String[] { Phone.NUMBER },
                        Data.MIMETYPE + "='" +     Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
                                + "'", null, null);
```

It works perfectly in my Android phone.

But some users say my app doesn't get all phone numbers from contacts and just part of them. I can't figure out the reason.. why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read all contact's phone numbers in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356084/read-all-contacts-phone-numbers-in-android)

Comment: No. My question is why it does not work well. It should work well according to http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html

Answer (score 3):

This will get the cursor holding base contact data, and will loop through the phone numbers the contact has, can have multiple.

```
Uri uri = data.getData();

Cursor cursor=ctx.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);


while (cursor.moveToNext()) { 
   String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)); 
   String hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)); 

   if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) { 
                    // You know have the number so now query it like this
    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
          null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId, 
          null, null); 

        while (phones.moveToNext()) { 
           String phoneNumber = phones.getString( 
                  phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));                 
        } 
        phones.close(); 
    } 
 }
```

Comment: But the method is too slow if I only want to all phone numbers. Anyway, thank you for reply.