# How do I get a first and last name list of contacts on Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-contacts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read contacts on Android 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721279/how-to-read-contacts-on-android-2-0)

I just want a `List<String>` of first name + last name from a devices contact list in Android. Should be something really simple, but I can't find any basic code.

Just looking for:

```
Steve Smith
Joe Shmo
Blah Davis
```

etc. all from the contacts on a users phone. I've already added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356084/read-all-contacts-phone-numbers-in-android

Answer (score 1):

```
    public List<String> getFullContactName(){

    List<String> name = new List<String>();

    String[] projection = new String[] {Data.DATA2, Data.DATA3};
    String where = Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'";
    Uri uri = Data.CONTENT_URI;

    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    // Make the query. 
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri,
                             projection, // Which columns to return 
                             where,       // Which rows to return
                             null,       // Selection arguments (none)
                             // Put the results in ascending order by name
                             null);

    String firstName, LastName;
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        firstName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Data.DATA2));
        lastName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Data.DATA3));
name.add(firstName + " " + lastName);           
    }

    cursor.close();
    cursor = null;
    return name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to be pulling a LOT more contacts into the list besides just the ones from my Phone app. Any way to get just the ones that appear in my Phone app?

Comment: If by phone app  you mean native contact application then ya this piece of code brings contact from it.