# how to get email id , Display name and phone number

Tags: java, android

I have used following query to get phone numbers,display name and email

```
String[] PROJECTION = new String[] { Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER,
            Email.DATA, Contacts._ID };

ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION,
                null, null, null);
```

But not getting Phone number using

```
phonenumber = cursor
                    .getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER_ID));
```

Comment: try to use this way cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);

Comment: not worked it always gives 1

Answer (score 0):

Try with..

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
    "DISPLAY_NAME = '" + NAME + "'", null, null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    String contactId =
        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    //
    //  Get all phone numbers.
    //
    Cursor phones = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
        Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null);
    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
        String number = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
        int type = phones.getInt(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));
        switch (type) {
            case Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                // do something with the Home number here...
                break;
            case Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                // do something with the Mobile number here...
                break;
            case Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                // do something with the Work number here...
                break;
            }
    }
    phones.close();
 }
cursor.close();
```

Or,see..

- http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/
- [Read all contact's phone numbers in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356084/read-all-contacts-phone-numbers-in-android)

Comment: I have tried this bt this query takes around 2 minutes.I think it is because we are fetching all the details.I don't want to get all the contact details.I just want Email,Phone number and Name.