# How to match DISPLAY_NAME and Phone.NUMBER in android content provider wile reading contacts

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, android-cursor

I have been practicing on contacts reading in android and I am getting the contacts and the  numbers but they are not arranged well. I mean the names assigned are not of the owners of the numbers. here is my code:

```
String [] projection= new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,};
    String [] phoneProjection= new String [] {Phone.NUMBER};


     ContentResolver crInstance=getContentResolver();

    final  Cursor name=crInstance.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
    final Cursor phone=crInstance.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, phoneProjection, null, null, null);
    contactview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contactview);
    name.moveToFirst();
    phone.moveToFirst();
    while (!name.isAfterLast()&&!phone.isAfterLast()){
        String pname=name.getString(name.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));



        contactview.append("Name:");
        contactview.append(pname);
        contactview.append("\n");


        final int contactNoColIndex= phone.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);

        String pnumber=phone.getString(contactNoColIndex);

        contactview.append("Phone:");
        contactview.append(pnumber);
        contactview.append("\n");
        contactview.append("\n");

        name.moveToNext();
        phone.moveToNext();
    }
    name.close();
    phone.close();
```

please help

Comment: Maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356084/read-all-contacts-phone-numbers-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code basically gets the Number first then uses it to search for the contact name.

`

```
Cursor c;
c= mydb.query("sms", null, null, null, null, null, null);
while (c.moveToNext()) {
String name = null;
String sender=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("phoneNo"));
String time=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("smstype"));
String smsbody=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("message"));
String[] projection = new String[]{
ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME};
Uri contacturi= Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(sender));
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();          
Cursor crc= cr.query(contacturi, projection, null, null, null);
if(crc.moveToNext()){   name=crc.getString(crc.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));  }   else{
name ="Unknown";
}
String senderid= name+" "+ sender;`
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple way:

```
 ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
 Cursor cursor = resolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        String name;
        String phone;

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            phone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

            // do what you want with the name and the phone number 

        }

    } else {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Cursor is empty");
    }

cursor.close();
```

Not forget to add permission into your manifest