# How to retrieve all the phone numbers with just one query

Tags: android

Is it possible to retrieve all the phone numbers with just one query(it's ok even if it's a bit slow)?

I found many topics that suggest to make query for the contact list and then a query for each contact but that's really slow.

The only solutions that I found with one query, retrieve just the main number. I need all the numbers of each contact plus the type.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read all contact's phone numbers in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356084/read-all-contacts-phone-numbers-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
 .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
 new String[] {Phone._ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER}, null, null,  Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
```

Comment: Is it also possible to avoid duplicates? I'm getting items with exactly the same name and number.

Comment: yes you can remove the duplicates
while (cursor.moveToNext()) { 
 phoneNumber = phones.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        name = phones.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
      
 int flag = 0
 if(list.size() == 0){
 list.add(new ProfileBean(name, phoneNumber));
 }
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
  if(!list.get(i).getProfileName().trim().equals(name)){
  flag = 1;
  }else{
   flag =0;
   break;
  }
    }
 if(flag == 1){
 list.add(new ProfileBean(name, phoneNumber));
 }
}