# Get all phone numbers of a contact Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to get all phone numbers and emails of contact with Xamarin.Android. I found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2356760/4965222 but I can't apply this raw android recipe for Xamarin.Android because not found where I can get `Phones._ID`, `Phones.TYPE`, `Phones.NUMBER`, `Phones.LABEL`, `People.Phones.CONTENT_DIRECTORY`. How to get this data without Xamarin.Mobile library?

Comment: "I can't apply this raw android recipe" - why not?  It's a short snippet of code - and all the necessary APIs should be available in Xamarin.  Maybe if you tell us what specific problem you have when you try to convert this code to C# we could better help you.

Comment: @jason Sorry, I was not clear. Maybe now this better describes problem

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Provider.Contacts+People+Phones/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After documentation research, I found the answer.

```
   //filtering phones related to a contact
   var phones = Application.Context.ContentResolver.Query(
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentUri,
        null,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.InterfaceConsts.ContactId
        + " = " + contactId, null, null);
    // getting phone numbers 
    while (phones.MoveToNext())
    {
        var number =
            phones.GetString(          //specify which column we want to get
                phones.GetColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number));
        // do work with number
    }
    phones.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the starting point

```
    public List<PersonContact> GetPhoneContacts()
    {
        var phoneContacts = new List<PersonContact>();

        using (var phones = ApplicationContext.ContentResolver.Query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentUri, null, null, null, null))
        {
            if (phones != null)
            {
                while (phones.MoveToNext())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string name = phones.GetString(phones.GetColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName));
                        string phoneNumber = phones.GetString(phones.GetColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number));

                        string[] words = name.Split(' ');
                        PersonContact contact = new PersonContact();
                        contact.FirstName = words[0];
                        if (words.Length > 1)
                            contact.LastName = words[1];
                        else
                            contact.LastName = ""; //no last name, is that ok?
                        contact.PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
                        phoneContacts.Add(contact);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //something wrong with one contact, may be display name is completely empty, decide what to do
                    }
                }
                phones.Close(); //not really neccessary, we have "using" above
            }
            //else we cannot get to phones, decide what to do
        }

        return phoneContacts;
    }


public class PersonContact
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```