# Android - Remove Duplicate Contacts

Tags: android, contacts

I am trying to display contacts in Recycler View everything is working fine but contacts are getting displayed twice or thrice.

**Here is the Code**

```
 RecyclerView recyclerView;
 List<Contacts> contactsList;
 ContactsAdapter adapter;

 public void getContactList() {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null,
            "UPPER(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + ") ASC");
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

        Contacts contacts = new Contacts(name, number);
        if (contactsList.contains(contacts)){
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        else {
            contactsList.add(contacts);
        }
        adapter = new ContactsAdapter(contactsList, getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

So, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: You are not clearing the list anywhere... Maybe the function happens more than once and the values are added to the list again and again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change **List** with **HashSet**. HashSet **prevents** to have duplicate items. Your final code should be like that:

```
 RecyclerView recyclerView;
 HashSet<Contacts> contactsSet;
 ContactsAdapter adapter;

 public void getContactList() {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null,
            "UPPER(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + ") ASC");
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

        Contacts contacts = new Contacts(name, number);
        contactsSet.add(contacts);
    }
    List<Contacts> contactsList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new ContactsAdapter(contactsList, getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass only phoneNumber as a key and phoneName as a value
You can use :

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("A", "1");
...
System.out.printf("Before: %s%n", map);

// Set in which we keep the existing values
Set<String> existing = new HashSet<>();
map = map.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(entry -> existing.add(entry.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
System.out.printf("After: %s%n", map);
```

for example :

```
Before: {A=1, B=2, C=2, D=3, E=3} After: {A=1, B=2, D=3}
```

Comment: So, Should I pass the name and number or I should pass contact object?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a couple of questions you should think about. Is the query wrong or is the way I save contacts wrong?

In your app should contacts be allowed to be duplicated? If no you could add a `unique constraint` to your migration. See [Sql Lite Unique Constraints](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-unique-constraint/)

If your DB should be accepting duplicate values, then you should add a column that signifies the unique ones to that user? Ie userId column or a place the contact is associated with and then add that into your query as Selection and SelectionArgs.

Lastly if you are just looking for a quick fix... you should dive deeper into your filtering.

Your code `contactsList.contains(contacts)` will never be true because you are always creating the contact on the line above. Then you are checking if your list contains that newly created one. Otherwise you can use the above solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/64535787/5398130

Answer (score 0):

You can override equals() method in class Contacts. This way your contactList.contains(Contact c) can evaluate to true if two contact objects are logically equals from your override method, and thus it will not add it to the list again.

```
     @Override
     public boolean equals(Object o){
          if(!o.getClass().equals(Contacts.class)) return false;
          Contact c2 = (Contact)o;
          // if phonenumber is unique to differentiate contact
          return c2.number.equals(number);
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can follow these steps on this page where i can provide the full solution here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64494108/13261376)